# Email id in postman response body is converted to small case

Tags: rest, postman

My API response has email id in capital letters but when I see the same in Postman the email id is in small letters.

Find the sample API response converted to string: email: **ABC@XYZ.com**, response body in `Postman`: Email:**abc@xyz.com**

Tried to search online for the review or how postman converts the response body but could not find anything. API response is `Base64` which needs to converted to string or `JSON`.

I want to understand why is the conversion of letters is happening and why is it specific to email. It is not happening to  other attributes.

Comment: where are you seeing it as caps

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6394

Comment: @PDHide seeing it in CAPS in API response of my code in debug mode and logs. While the same response is lower case in postman/talend.

Comment: what happens if you view in browser ?